# Expected number of throws of 6 dice until all 6 faces appear

Tags: probability

Just have a small problem solving this puzzle found online.

**On average, how many times do 
you need to roll six dice together, to 
get all six different sides on each die. it is a group roll 6 dice together**

Comment: i mean, rolling 6 Dice, getting each side only once.  How many times should i roll 6 dice together to get 6 different sides for each dice in that group roll.

Comment: What have you tried? What do you know? Are you familiar with the concept of expectation?

Comment: OK, but this should be easier because the probability of such a roll is fairly low.  We can imagine that "die 1" must be 1, "die 2" must be 2, etc.  This means there is exactly _one_ way to get this roll out of $6^6 = 46656$ possible rolls.  Now we realize that the order does not matter and thus there are $6! = 720$ different permutations of the original ordering, thus there is a $p = \frac{6*5*4*3*2 }{6*6*6*6*6*6} = \frac{5*4*3*2}{6*6*6*6*6} = \frac{5*4*2}{6*6*6*6*2} = \frac{5*4}{6*6*6*6} = \frac{5}{6*6*3*3} = \frac{5}{324}$.

Comment: I know that for only one dice rolled. getting each different sides  it is 1+6/5 + 6/4 + 6/3 +6/2 + 6/1 = 14.7 . but for 6 dices and 6 different sides should i just add 14.7*6 times?

Comment: With a $p = \frac{5}{324}$, the expected value in $n$ rolls is $E = pn = n\frac{5}{324}$.  Setting that to $1$, we should get that the expected number of rolls (on average) is $\frac{324}{5} = 64.8$

Comment: @Jared thanks alot it much clear now. but can u tell me what does 6^6 shows? and what does 6! shows here?

Comment: It's worth noting that you _should not_ expect to actually get your result in, let's say, 65 rolls--in fact there's a slightly higher than 50% chance that you will get your result in as many rolls.

Comment: @HasnainAli $6^6$ represents the number of _permutations_ if we label each die.  Specifically a roll of 1,2,3,4,5,6 is "different" than a roll of 2,1,3,4,5,6 (because different dice gave the value of 1 and 2)--even though they _both_ satisfy your result.  This is why we have to multiply by $6!$, because that's the number of different ways of ordering 1,2,3,4,5,6.  This isn't a simple combination problem (and I think would be difficult, if not impossible, to characterize as such).

Comment: @Jared Thanks so Much, It more clear to me . cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When we roll the $6$ dice, say consecutively, there are $6^6$ possible outcomes. There are $6!$ outcomes where the results are all different, so the probability $p$ that the outcomes are all different is given by $p=\frac{6!}{6^6}$.

The random variable  $X$ that measures the number of times  that we do the rolling of six until all numbers are different has *geometric* distribution with parameter $p$. It is a standard result that the expectation of $X$ is $\frac{1}{p}$.

Comment: Is this really a geometric distribution?  I'm not sure (which is why I'm asking).  To me this is a Bernoulli Random Variable where "success" is that all numbers show up in a single roll.  Maybe you're thinking about it differently than me though.

Comment: The rolling of the $6$ dice gives us a Bernoulli random variable with probability of success equal to the $p$ of the answer. But we repeat the rolling of the six until we get a success, and the random variable of the OP is the number of six-rolls until we get a success. **This** random variable has geometric distribution.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple geometric distribution problem once you work out the chances of this happening on your first try (first toss of six collective dice).

In that first try, there is a $\frac{6!}{6^6}$ chance of this happening. So the expected value is the reciprocal: $\frac{6^6}{6!}=64.8$ .